# HP LaserJet wont print OCR'ed file or Power Point file, sent from OSX

Tags: pdf, printing, ocr

I've got an HP Colour LaserJet Pro MFP M281fdw printer.

The printer works fine for word docs, images etc and PDFs (which are not OCR'ed)

If a PDF has been created from a scanned document then OCR'ed the file will fail to print.

By fail to print i mean :

When i try to print a 50 Page OCR'ed PDF the first page that contains no OCR'ed text prints fine, but the printer stalls and dosent print any of the other pages, i get an error on my laptop something allong the lines of can not connect to printer. If it have the same document but not OCR'ed and print it, it works fine.

When i try to print a 3 page OCR'ed PDF, none of the pages print, but instead the printer prints an error page, with the following :

```
ERROR : undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND : New
STACK :
/AAAAB+ *Times
/FontName
```

---

Ive spoken to HP Support and apparently this is a known issue they added the following :

- The issue Prints from Power Point (I don't do any work in Power Point so have not verified)
- The issue is to do with OSX. (I have tried using both the HP provided driver and the standard generic drivers, but the issue continues, apparently its to do with the way OSX handles printing, prior to the print being sent to the print driver.
- The issue is not present on Windows (I have not confirmed)

Are there any known workarounds to this issue, other than if i want to print an OCR'ed document, convert it to a non OCR'ed doc first?

My laptop is running OSX 10.13.6.x, my laptop is connected to the network via Wifi.

The printer is connected to the network via a wired connection.

Comment: [This Support page](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Since-update-to-Mojave-Mac-will-not-print-PDF-to-Laser-Jet/td-p/6861402) at HP has a solution to a PDF printing problem that revolves around the network connection (WiFi in particular.) If the devices you are dealing with are connected with WiFi, perhaps this info will help.

Comment: Does "Open in Preview" from the print dialog, and printing from Preview afterwards, work?

Comment: When you say "Fail to Print", what exactly happens; what error messages do you get?
What OS are you on? There were bugs in PDF in Sierra, I think, relating to invisible layers used in OCRring. It also depended on what application created the OCR.

Comment: Are you using Preview to print the PDF with the OCR’d text?  Try downloading and using [Adobe’s native PDF viewer for Mac](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html)

Comment: Thanks @Allan i use a mixture of acrobat pro and OSX preview.app for PDF viewing daily, cant re-call which i used for the tests, will try again with both and advise

Comment: Ive done some further testing on this and using the "secure airprint" driver i can get smaller OCR'ed files to print (c. 2mb). But sending larger OCR'ed files (c. 50mb) fails(nothing prints and the print queue just hangs)